# Create indexed view

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

My table structure is below :

```
MyTable (ID Int, AccID1 Int, AccID2 Int, AccID3 int)

 ID      AccID1      AccID2      AccID3
----    --------    --------    --------
  1        12          2          NULL
  2        4           12           1
  3       NULL        NULL          5
  4        7          NULL          1
```

I want to create indexed view with below output :

```
 ID    Level     Value
----   -----    -------
 1       1         12
 1       2         2 
 2       1         4
 2       2         12
 2       3         1
 3       3         5
 4       1         7
 4       3         1
```

EDIT :

My table is very huge and I want to have above output.
I can Get my query such as below :

```
Select  ID,
        Case StrLevel
            When  'AccID1' Then 1
            When  'AccID2' Then 2
            Else 3
        End AS [Level],
        AccID as Value
From    (
        Select A.ID, A.AccID1, A.AccID2, A.AccID3
        From MyTable A
        )as p
UNPIVOT (AccID FOR [StrLevel] IN (AccID1, AccID2, AccID3)) AS unpvt
```

or

```
Select *
from (
        select MyTable.ID,
                num.n as [Level],
                Case Num.n
                    When 1 Then MyTable.AccID1
                    When 2 Then MyTable.AccID2
                    Else MyTable.AccID3
                End AS AccID
        from myTable
        cross join (select 1
                    union select 2
                    union select 3)Num(n)
    )Z
Where Z.AccID IS NOT NULL
```

or

```
    Select  A.ID,
            2 AS [Level],
            A.AccID1 AS AccID
     From MyTable A
     Where A.AccID1 IS NOT NULL

    Union

    Select  A.ID,
            2 AS [Level],
            A.AccID2
     From MyTable A
     Where A.AccID2 IS NOT NULL

    Union

    Select  A.ID,
            3 AS [Level],
            A.AccID3
     From MyTable A
     Where A.AccID3 IS NOT NULL
```

But Above query is slow and I want to have indexed view to have better performance.
and in indexed view I can't use `UNION` or `UNPIVOT` or `CROSS JOIN` in indexed view.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) Also while your schema is well presented and clear, what you are actually asking is not. Please edit the question so that what you are asking is more clear, and what you have tried so far, and where you are encountering problems.

Comment: You need `UNPIVOT`. Can't remember if that's allowed in indexed views though. And that's assuming that the row `2, 3 ,5` in the desired results is meant to have value of 1 not 5.

Comment: I dont use `UNPIVOT` in my query for create indexed view.

Comment: I guess upgrading to 2012 is out of the question? I notice that `PIVOT` no longer appears in the [list of restrictions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx#Restrictions), though I haven't tried this out yet. As is (in 2008), you're unlikely to find a workaround - most times, if you hit a restriction, any re-working of the query will hit another one.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Unfortunately this appears to be an ommission from the list of restrictions, rather than indexed views allowing in in 2012. I tried it on my local version of 2012 and on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6) and got the standard error message *Cannot create index on view dbo.MyView because it uses the UNPIVOT operator. Consider not indexing this view.*

Comment: If rearranging your query to make use of indexes already on your table is not an option then depending on how frequent the changes are to your table and how current you need the data to be you could try creating a new table, maintained by a nightly job that contains the data in the format you require and build indexes on this. Or store your data in the layout required for the view and create a new view to store this in the layout of your current table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you created a Numbers table to essentially do the work of your illegal `CROSS JOIN`?

```
Create Table Numbers (number INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY) 
Go

Insert Numbers 
Select top 30000 row_number() over (order by (select 1)) as rn
from sys.all_objects s1 cross join sys.all_objects s2
go

Create view v_unpivot with schemabinding
as  
Select MyTable.ID,
        n.number as [Level],
        Case n.number
            When 1 Then MyTable.AccID1
            When 2 Then MyTable.AccID2
            Else MyTable.AccID3
        End AS AccID
From dbo.Mytable
Join dbo.Numbers n on n.number BETWEEN 1 AND 3 
go

Create unique clustered index pk_v_unpivot on v_unpivot (ID, [Level]) 
go

Select 
  ID,
  [Level],
  AccID
From v_unpivot with (noexpand)
Where AccID IS NOT NULL 
Order by ID, [Level]
```

The `WHERE AccID IS NOT NULL` must be part of the query because derived tables are not allowed in indexed views.